# How to check resume function for Embulk plugin

Tags: jdbc, resume, bulk-load

Currently I'm developing embulk. I implemented resume function for my plugin but I can't confirm operation by test for resume function. How to test resume function ? How to implement a transaction fail during run embulk to check resume function?

Answer (score 0):

Did you ask the same question on the Github Issue?

Please see: [How to check resume function for plugin](https://github.com/embulk/embulk/issues/1187)